# Import multiple node reference from CSV using feeds

Tags: 6, feeds, importing-exporting

I am trying to import multiple node references for one node using feeds. How should my CSV look like for that??

Will this work :

```
"title","description","status","code","details",("contact1","contact2", ..., "contactN" );
```

given that I have another content type named **contact** with titles *contact1*, *contact2,* ..., to *contactN*

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you the [Node Import](http://drupal.org/project/node_import) module for Drupal 6. It's very powerful and works great with references.

Comment: thks..I am going to check that